# In Python OOP When Calling Class Variable Should self or Class Name be used?

Tags: python, oop

I am very rusty on OOP. Now my question is, how exactly would I go about calling a class variable?

I know to call an `__init__` variable you would do the following:

```
class HelloWorld:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "Hello"

    def world(self):
        print self.hello + "World"
```

How do I call a variable not initialized in the class though? Which of the following would be correct?

```
class HelloWorld:

    hello = "Hello"

    def world(self):
        #Do I use self?
        print self.hello + "World"
        #Do I use the class name?
        print HelloWorld.hello + "World"
```

I am just confused on whether I should be using `self` or the class name. Most examples I see are using `self`, but the one on Tutorials Point uses the class's name. Please elaborate, thank you!

Comment: Yes thank you! Kinda missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HelloWorld.hello` does not require an instance of `HelloWorld` to be used. This might be used in a case where a value should be common among all instances of `HelloWorld`. `self.hello` belongs to the instance and could be different across instances of `HelloWorld`.

The code

```
class HelloWorld:

    hello = "Hello"

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.hello = text

    def world(self):
        #Do I use self?
        print self.hello + "World"
        #Do I use the class name?
        print HelloWorld.hello + "World"

print HelloWorld.hello
print HelloWorld('Goodbye').hello

MyInstance = HelloWorld('Goodbye')
MyInstance.world()
```

outputs

```
Hello
Goodbye
GoodbyeWorld
HelloWorld
```

Comment: Ok so basically, whenever referring to a variable defined outside of `__init__` use `classname.variablename` to reference it?

Comment: A member of a class does not need to be defined in `__init__`. The real answer is to understand if the variable was defined by the class or the instance. If you find yourself needing to create a `HelloWorld` object to access the variable, which is the case with `self.hello` then don't use `classname.variablename`. Otherwise you can use `classname.variablename`.

Comment: @MichaelJones No, it depends on the behaviour you want to achieve. As I and mgilson show there are cases where you want to make that value overridable by instances/derived classes, and other times not. So **it depends**.

Comment: Ok, I guess one of the biggest issues is I am not understanding this line `HelloWorld('Goodbye').hello` What does that do?

Comment: The line `HelloWorld('Goodbye').hello` creates a `HelloWorld` object and then accesses the `hello` member belonging to that object. It is the same as `object = HelloWorld('Goodbye')` and then `print object.hello`

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you, not realizing `HelloWorld('Goodbye')` was the syntax for creating a new object. Also not realizing I could do both statements in one line. Thank You!!!

Comment: @MichaelJones You're welcome. Take a look at the python docs. They may be confusing at first, but I'm sure if you read it over a couple of times and try out the code it will make sense. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'll want to use `self` here.  This allows for a few nice "tricks" to be played.  e.g. You can override `hello` in a subclass:

```
class GreetWorld(HelloWorld):
    hello = "Greetings"
```

Or you can re-set the attribute on a per-instance basis:

```
hw = HelloWorld()
hw.hello = 'Hey, How are you'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, the results are well defined and in that case they will do the same.

Note however that this changes when you have derived classes:

```
class Base:
    hello = 'A'

    def greet(self):
        print(self.hello)

    def greet2(self):
        print(Base.hello)


class Derived(Base):
    hello = 'B'

d = Derived()
d.greet()   # prints B
d.greet2()  # prints A
```

Moreover in some cases you could have *instances* that use that attribute to override the class value:

```
class Base:
    hello = 'A'
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        if val is not None:
            self.hello = 'B'
    def greet(self):
        print(self.hello)


A = Base()
B = Base()
A.greet()    # A
B.greet('B') # B
A.greet()    # *still* A
```

So if you want to be sure that the value used is precisely the one of that class use the explicit class name, otherwise use `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them will work. When you have `self` passed in to the method `self == HelloWorld`

```
class HelloWorld:
    hello = "hello"
    def world(self):
        print self.hello + "World"
```

But when self is not passed in to method i.e, static method then use

```
class HelloWorld:
    hello = "hello"
    @staticmethod
    def world():
        print HelloWorld.hello
```